# I'd like to add a hint to my spinner. How can I do that?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, spinner, android-spinner

I want to add a hint to my spinner.

I get my spinner from a database, and I want before chose spinner show hint in my spinner. How to add hint in my spinner?

This my code:

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()
            //edittext1.setText(name)

            spin1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()
            String idnya = spin1.substring(0,spin1.indexOf('-'))
            Log.e("spin",""+spin1)
            setSpinner2(idnya)
            spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

// set spinner pertama (1)
public void setSpinner1(String koddeee) {
    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip)
    String query1 = "select id,namabarang from Jenis_Barang where nomorjenis = '"+koddeee+"' "
    Log.e("query",""+query1)

    try {
        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip)
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query1)
        rs = stmt.executeQuery()

        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {

            id = rs.getString(1)
            String nama = rs.getString(2)

            data.add(id+"-"+nama)
        }

        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0])
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data)
        spinner1.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("errora",""+e.getMessage())
```